# How to replace zeros and put a decimal number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want MonthlyPayment have column float `PaymentAmount` *numeric(18,3)*

I have data like this in PaymentAmount:

```
PaymentAmount
--------------
1230.25
829122.35
```

I want to make the returning Payment amount like this:

```
PaymentAmount
--------------
000000001230.25
000000829122.35
```

I used this query but It returns:

```
PaymentAmount
--------------
000000000001230
000000000829122
```

the query :

```
SELECT ISNULL(replace(str(MonthlyPayment.PaymentAmount,15,0),' ','0'),SPACE(15)) 
FROM MonthlyPayment
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with any version of SQL Server

```
SELECT RIGHT('000000000000' + CAST(CAST(PaymentAmount AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS VARCHAR(20)),15)
FROM MonthlyPayment

Eample:

DECLARE @PaymentAmount AS DECIMAL (18,3) = 1230.256;
SELECT RIGHT('000000000000' + CAST(CAST(@PaymentAmount AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS VARCHAR(20)),15)

DECLARE @PaymentAmount1 AS DECIMAL (18,3) = 829122.35;
SELECT RIGHT('000000000000' + CAST(CAST(@PaymentAmount1 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) AS VARCHAR(20)),15)
```

Comment: This is great, but I think you would first need to cast `PaymentAmount` to `DECIMAL(14, 2)` and then cast this to `VARCHAR`.

Comment: the problem is that the column type is numeric(18,3) so it will retrieve 3 decimal places not just 2 :/ .. can u help with other solution or edit it ?

Comment: @BishoyEzzat I just edited this answer, the first query should work for you.

Comment: Aha ... I see the new answer .. Thanks :)

Comment: @Bishoy Ezzat just edited my answer to work with 3 deciaml places

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server 2012 + you can use [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
SELECT FORMAT(PaymentAmount, '00000000000#.##')
FROM MonthlyPayment
```

Sample execution:

```
DECLARE @PaymentAmount AS DECIMAL (18,2) = 1230.25;
SELECT FORMAT(@PaymentAmount,'00000000000#.##');
-- OUTPUT: 000000001230.25

DECLARE @PaymentAmount1 AS DECIMAL (18,2) = 829122.35;
SELECT FORMAT(@PaymentAmount1,'00000000000#.##');
-- OUTPUT: 000000829122.35
```

Comment: unfortunately, this will not be accepted in the work :/, but it is a good solution ... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If your version of SQL Server has `REPLICATE` available, then you can carefully pad the `PaymentAmount` column with the required number of zeroes to give the total string a width of 15 characters.

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0',
                 15 - LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DECIMAL(14, 2), PaymentAmount))))
     + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DECIMAL(14, 2), PaymentAmount))
FROM MonthlyPayment
```

Comment: can you just add 2 zeros after the decimal point ? ... because some data has .324 , .021 and .99 I just want 2 decimal places not 3 decimal places ?

Comment: What is the type of the `PaymentAmount` column?

Comment: it is numeric(18, 3)

Comment: Then if you go with my solution, you will first have to cast to a number with two decimal places, and then cast that number to a `varchar`.